# MySQL JOIN multiple columns with corresponding ID

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, one with names of teams, the other holds various selections made by users, each of which is represented by the team's team_id. I want to be able to display the actual team names for each, but can't figure out how the join would work.

Table 1

user_id(int), selection1(int), selection2(int), selection3(int)

Table 2

team_id(int), team_name(varchar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three joins:

```
select u.user_id, t1.team_name as team_name1, t2.team_name as team_name2,
       t3.team_name as team_name3
from users u left outer join
     teams t1
     on u.selection1 = t1.team_id left outer join
     teams t2
     on u.selection2 = t2.team_id left outer join
     teams t3
     on u.selection3 = t3.team_id;
```

Comment: what do t1, t2, and t3 represent? there's only one teams table.

Comment: @KyleHagler . . . They are table aliases, and an important part of the SQL language.  For instance, they let you use the same table several times in a query -- when you need it.